# Is there an optimal way for writing lots of tiny files with PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, partitioning

I have a job that requires having to write a single JSON file to s3 for each row in a Spark dataframe (which then gets picked up by another process).

```
df.repartition(col("id")).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy(col("id")).json(
        f"s3://bucket/path/to/file"
    )
```

These datasets often consist of 100k rows (sometimes 1m+) and take a very long time to write. I understand that large numbers of small files is not great for read performance but is this also the case for writes? Or is there something that can be done with partitioning to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this, you will only suffer pain.  S3 was designed to be cheap long-term storage optimized for large files.  It was design so the 'prefix' (directory path) leads to a bucket that provides files.  If you want to optimize reads and writes you want to develop several buckets to write to at the same time.  This means you want to actually modify the directory path(prefix) to the bucket with the most amount of variation to increase the number of buckets that you write to.

Example of mulitple files being written to the same bucket:

```
  S3:/mydrive/mystuff/2020-12-31
  S3:/mydrive/mystuff/2020-12-30
  S3:/mydrive/mystuff/2020-12-29
```

This is because they [all share the same bucket prefix](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html)  --> `S3:/mydrive/mystuff/`
What if instead you flipped the part that changes? Now you have different buckets being used as you are writing to different buckets.([prefix](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/general/latest/gr/glos-chap.html#keyprefix) is different)

```
  S3:2020-12-31/mydrive/mystuff/
  S3:2020-12-30/mydrive/mystuff/
  S3:2020-12-29/mydrive/mystuff/
```

This change will help with read/write speed as different buckets will be used.  It will not solve the problem that S3 doesn't actually use directories to direct you to files.  As I said a prefix is actually just a pointer to the bucket.  It then searches against all files you have written, to find the file that exists in your bucket.  This is why tons of small files makes things worse, the lookup time for files takes longer and longer the more files you write.  Because this lookup is expensive it's much faster to write larger files and make the cost of lookup minimized.